# Spatially matching Landsat images in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, landsat

I'm trying to look at the desiccation of a lake over a number of years using images from different Landsats. However when I import the different years into arcmap they are completely unsynchronized. I have consider it might be a case of manually georeferencing, but i may be wrong.

What is the quickest way to align them?

Comment: You need to provide us with more information. Where are you getting the information from? What file format? Are your images projected? Are they georeferenced already?

Comment: Sorry - they are from USGS Glovis, they are all in TIF format, they are all in WGS_1984_UTM_zone_19N and they are all already geoferenced.

Comment: Are you saying that the georeferencing is wrong, or is it that when you add the data ArcMap ignores the georeferencing?

Answer (score 1):

If, when you say "unsynchronized", you mean that the raster cells don't align properly, then you should look at using the Snap Raster property in the ArcToolbox/Geoprocessing environment settings.

That will help ensure that the pixels line up exactly.

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/how-snap-raster-environment-works.htm